# examples of Firebase cloud messaging XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently use Google Cloud Messaging using HTTP is most all of my apps on Google Play.  I'm thinking of beginning to use Firebase Cloud Messaging with XMPP.  I've read through all the stuff at firebase.google.com/docs.

I find good docs on how to receive messages in a firebase Android client There are also good docs on the XMPP stanzas and the message formats but I can't find any code examples of how to send and receive that actual XMPP messages on my server.

My servers are ASP.NET Web API REST servers using C# but I would like to find examples in any environment and language.

Are there examples anywhere?

Comment: See this GitHub sample it has both a Go and Java server: https://github.com/googlesamples/friendlyping/tree/master/server. In both cases a library is used to handle the XMPP protocol so the implementation should be clear and you can migrate it to C# good luck.

Comment: Arthur: The matriX XMPP SDK is about $2,000 per developer.  Looks like I'll have to stick with HTTP.

Comment: Sticking with HTTP is a valid option, but I'd be very surprised if there are no free C# XMPP libraries.